# pass paramenter to document ready function from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, call

I have this code in a separate js-file to load content into a page without reloading the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//Catch the form's submit event:
$('#skipreload').submit(function() {
    //Create AJAX call:
    $.ajax({
        //Get form data:
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        //GET or POST method:
        type: 'GET',
        //The file to call:
        url: 'webaddress.php',
        //On success update div with response:
        success: function(response) {
            $('#form_output').html(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

I call the function in a page like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script src="js/script.js">
<!-- Want to create variable to pass parameter to document ready function here -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
(...)
```

Now I want to pass the 'webaddress.php'-url as a parameter from the HTML-page to the script.js-file and its submit function, but I cannot make this work. Does someone know how this can be done?

Comment: You can create a global variable, which will be accessible in JS file

Comment: This would be a really bad solution to whatever your actual problem is.Its better to provide more information about your problem scenario.

Comment: I want to point several pages with different urls to the specific script, that's why I want to replace the url in the script to some kind of variable and only pass a parameter from each page holding the actual url. That is, so I don't need to repeat the whole javascript for each page.

Comment: Any variable can't the passed the way you are trying. Keeping the value in an hidden field then from script read the value is might be a solution not the best one though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Satpal already mentioned, you could create a global variable inside of your HTML which will be accessible in the external script

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>var myUrl = 'webaddress.php';</script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
(...)
```

In script.js:

```
url: myUrl,
```

Be careful: In that case you must not forget to provide this value in each HTML file that uses script.js, otherwise you will get "undefined" for myUrl.

Comment: Ok, so it wasn't more difficult than that, thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

Keep it in a div and load its value:

**EDITED**

```
<div id='url' style='display:none'>webaddress.php</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = $("#url").text();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

**OR**

```
<input type='hidden' id='url' value='webaddress.php' />

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = $("#url").val();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Comment: There is no `value` property on a div

Comment: If you don't understand the technology at hand and/or the question, don't just throw a random answer up.

Comment: @AndréDion If he wants to push a value to the script from the page, is this a unacceptable answer?? I mean, he wants a value in `$(document).ready()`...putting it in the document body would serve the purpose...

Comment: You should probably mention that the div should normally be hidden from view ... maybe you could use a hidden text input instead (and revert to .val())